# MS Office Sharepoint 2007 FARM Backup Can't Restore

Tags: 2007, sharepont

I would like to ask for your help regarding on the restoration of our sharepoint site. Currently, our server just died and our Operating System has been corrupted. Now, we have to install a new OS.

My problem is, I cannot restore my Sharepoint 2007 site.
My last backup was through Central Administration.

Can anyone help me with the issue?
Also, I couldn't find any MOSS2007 installer in the internet.

Is there any way I could restore it on a new version of Sharepoint?

Thanks a lot.